# Net Core - .Include() results in loop causing Visual Studio debug to crash

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, visual-studio-2017, eager-loading

My database has a one-to-many relation between "UsageRecord" and "Dimension"

[image: Database diagram]

This is modelled as follows (using a Database-First approach):

```
public partial class Dimension
    {               
        ...          
        public virtual ICollection<UsageRecord> UsageRecord { get; set; }       
    }
```

Usage Record class:

```
      public partial class UsageRecord
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            ...
            public long DimensionId { get; set; }    
            public virtual Dimension Dimension { get; set; }              
        }
```

So, if i query the list of UsageRecords (EagerLoading):

```
_context.Set<UsageRecord>.Where(x => x.ProductId == productId).ToList()
```

i get a list of UsageRecord objects I can navigate through during debug:
[image: usage record]

Please notice that the Dimension object is null, and this is correct since i haven't  included it in the query.

Now, If i try to include it, the application crashes:

```
_context.Set<UsageRecord>.Where(x => x.ProductId == productId).Include(p => p.Dimension).ToList();
```

[image: crash]

Postman exits with a 502 error, and the VS Debug first shows a list of question marks "?" before crashing.

I think this is due to the fact that by Including the Dimension object, this loops through the list of UsageRecords attached and then the Dimension again and again.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: In this case you need to create an anonymous type to avoid infinite loop on serialization or set up your serializer to ignore the loops

Comment: Yes it seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7564

It is MVC related and can be "solved" by ignoring loops on serialization at Startup: 
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

Comment: So, at this moment you can solve your requirement creating a view model or anonymous type, have you solved ?

Comment: I solved it thanks to the link and the line of code provided in my previous comment

Comment: I'll an answer for reference according to your feedback

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve your result from LINQ query you can solve your issue in these ways:

- Configure your serializer to ignore loops
- Create a view model for your controller's action
- Use anonymous type from Select result in your controller's action

Comment: ***"Create a view model for your controller's action"*** solved the issue I had.